# Visual Paradigm Ribbon Bar vs Classic

Tags: visual-paradigm

### Question

A colleague and I both have `visual paradigm 12 enterprise` installed.
On my own computer I have the classic menu bar:

[image]

On the colleague's computer it is the same version but it displays a `ribbon bar`.
We both prefer the classic menu.

What could be a reason for this? Could it be cause she installed `visual paradigm 13` on the same machine?

### Update

Using the answer from @Karol, below is a screenshot pointing to the specific dialogs/buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it in Application Option (Ribbon):

Window -> Application Options -> Appearance (tab) -> User Interface.

Change UI to **Classic** and **restart VP**.

Comment: Thank you, it's quite hidden away!